# is it possible that visual studio didn't print negative exponent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I almost finish an application that I make by visual studio 2010, but the value from the application is different from the computation, I thought maybe visual studio 2010 set the limit for the number of digits in listview.
the thing I want to ask: is it possible that visual studio didn't print negative exponent? because in my case, exponent value that is visible only to 7.56789-E06 then 7.56789-E05 and then back to 0.000756789.but suddenly appear 7.123486182 (without '-E ').

Comment: Its possible that the column width isn't large enough, but its not going to remove data unless you tell it to. If you want to force exponential notation, you should use the appropriate format string.

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString if you aren't specifying a format string the default "G" is used, and the number of significant digits depends on the type.

Comment: In cases like this I start with the assumption that the compiler has it right and I've got a bug in my code...

Comment: @ronbeyer okay, your information is very helpful. thank you

Comment: @John3136 in my case...I don't think so, because in first looping until about twentieth. the value is exactly the same with computation result..